Excel VBA: Move to next row to display to textboxes
i was able to do this a few years back with offset and whatever it was called. but it was close to 10 years ago and I forgot it.
So onload/initialize, i want to point to row number 2. Then the left and right button should move the pointer to the next row of data to display in the the 2 textboxes.
Please disregard commandbutton3 there. Thanks!
Here's the code that i got but it only moves 1 row.
 
Private Sub btn_Next_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim CurRow As Long

Set ws1 = Sheets("TestSheet")

CurRow = 2

txtName.Text = ws1.Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(1, 0)

txtType.Text = ws1.Cells(CurRow, 2).Offset(1, 0)

CurRow = CurRow + 1

End Sub



Try Activecell.Offset(1,0).

but activecell could be anywhere right? or where the cursor is at?

Where the cursor is.

Try this mod.
Dim CurRow As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

CurRow = 1

End Sub



Private Sub btn_Next_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("TestSheet")

CurRow = CurRow + 1
txtName.Text = ws1.Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(1, 0)
txtType.Text = ws1.Cells(CurRow, 2).Offset(1, 0)


End Sub

One experiment for the back button
Private Sub btn_Previous_Click()   'apply the name of the button

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("TestSheet")

If CurRow > 2 then
    CurRow = CurRow - 1
    txtName.Text = ws1.Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(1, 0)
    txtType.Text = ws1.Cells(CurRow, 2).Offset(1, 0)
End If

End Sub

Defined CurRow with module scope it will preserve its value between the calls.

looks like it's working but what do i do for the back button now? i tried this but it's not working txtName.Text = ws1.Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(-1, 0)
txtType.Text = ws1.Cells(CurRow, 2).Offset(-1, 0)
CurRow = CurRow - 1

Added a possible workaround to my answer. Applied a mod. for avoiding the repeat of displaying the same row when direction changed in the clicks.

hey black cat, thanks a bunch. but some weird behavior, i sometimes need to double click the buttons for it to work. any thoughts on that?

Look the edited code. I worked just on that issue.

thanks Black cat, it's working now! but i had to revert to the <> 1 condition otherwise, default row #2  will not show up (Test Name and Test Type with no number). thanks a bunch!!!!
